# Using two different networks at the same time

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, ftp, ethernet

I am wanting to setup an old PC that uses Windows 7 as a private FTP server, however, I've run into issues after connecting the PC to a second network.

The server PC is currently connected to my own private router over an ethernet connection, and my university network over a wireless connection. I want to have it setup so that all FTP traffic is only done over the ethernet connection, and so that all internet traffic is only done over the wireless connection. As of now, the PC only uses the wireless connection for both FTP and internet, and ignores the ethernet connection altogether.

The wireless connection uses a USB network adapter whereas the ethernet connection uses a PCIe adapter. I've created a network bridge between the two so that Windows communicates with both my private network and the university network, and I've set the bridge's metric to be 10, so that Windows prefers the bridged connection over any others.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: I'm sort of confused why you want that. Can't you just disconnect from wireless and only use Ethernet for FTP and whatever else. Plus if this is an old PC you won't really be using it for much more than FTP anyways. Also, I'm not sure how you've setup your FTP server but I highly recommend the [FileZilla](http://www.howtogeek.com/140352/how-to-host-an-ftp-server-on-windows-with-filezilla/) server.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have two networks.  If both the internet and FTP is accessible via a single network card, then you probalby have a single network.  Can you [edit] your post and try and describe the connectivity in a bit more detail?

Comment: I've updated the post to include new relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup two networks your going to want to first setup two separate subnets. For example if the universal network is 10.1.0.0/16 You would want to make your private network 192.168.0.0/24.

Then configure your windows firewall. Set the Universal Network your wireless network as Public and block FTP on the windows firewall and set the private network your Ethernet to home and allow ftp traffic. Then when you want to connect to your ftp server use the 192.168.0.* address.